# use `bower init` within MinTTY

Tags: mintty

I'm trying to use `bower init` from a MinTTY shell on Windows 8.1 x64 but I get this error:

```
sh-3.1$ bower init
bower ENOINT        Register requires an interactive shell
```

How can I use this command inside MinTTY?

Answer (score 1):

This is because bower requires nodejs and unfortunately nodejs doesnt support cygwin - https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installation#building-on-cygwin